# How can I have the same javascript code respond to multiple ajax calls?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I would like to have the two action respond with one javascript template publication.js.erb instead of using a file.js.erb for each action.

```
##AJAX CALLBACKS##


def publish
    @myth = Myth.find(params[:id])
    if @myth.update_attributes(:status=>2)
      #change status to publish
      @msg  = "Your Myth has been Published"
      @type = "alert-success"
    else
      @msg  = "Your Myth has not been Published"
      @type = "error-success"
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def unpublish
    @myth = Myth.find(params[:id])
    if @myth.update_attributes(:status=>0)
      #change status to publish
      @msg  = "Your Myth has been Unpublished"
      @type = "alert-success"
    else
      @msg  = "Your Myth has not been Unpublished"
      @type = "error-success"
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In each of your `respond_to` blocks, just do this:

```
format.js { render 'publication' }
```

This will make both actions render the same template file.